# SQL: Field Consolidation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

While using this query, I am have a result that I want, but I need to consolidate the Beer.Name instances. Such that, with my output I have multiple entries of Beer.Name and their quantities, when I would like to consolidate both the CustomerID and Beer.Name into single entities. How would I do this?

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, Beer.Name,sum (quantitysupplied)as 'Total Quantity'
FROM Customer C
INNER JOIN CustomerOrder
    ON C.CustomerID = CustomerOrder.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN CustomerOrderLine
    ON CustomerOrderLine.CustomerOrderID = CustomerOrder.CustomerOrderID 
INNER JOIN Product
    ON CustomerOrderLine.ProductID =Product.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Beer
    ON Product.BeerID = Beer.BeerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerID, Beer.Name, CustomerType
HAVING CustomerType LIKE 'C'
```

Thank you.

This is the output:

```
      CustomerID  Name                           Total Quantity
 ----------- ------------------------------ --------------
  1001        Ale Heads                      11
 1002        Ale Heads                      8
  1003        Ale Heads                      13
  1004        Ale Heads                      3
  1006        Ale Heads                      4
  1007        Ale Heads                      14
  1008        Ale Heads                      4
 1009        Ale Heads                      4
```

It is quite long, but it this is pretty representative, I want to have only one instance of the beer name and Customer ID consolidated into something else.

Comment: Could you write out your current output and what you want it to look like? I don't quite understand.

Comment: based on your explanation it sounds like you want this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: What do you want the desired result to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
SELECT CAST(C.CustomerID AS varchar) + ': ' + Beer.Name AS CustomerBeer, Sum(quantitysupplied) AS 'Total Quantity'
FROM etc.
```